# Can you tell SCP to cancel [as opposed to renaming] if file is present?

Tags: ssh, files, rsync, transfer, scp

In order to help avoid generating errors, I need a way to stop an automated `scp` script to stop from overwriting files if they are already present on the remote folder, and just do nothing instead.

Is this possible?

Comment: Don't think accept via a script...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename Duplicate Files when using SCP (Secure Copy)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/832363/rename-duplicate-files-when-using-scp-secure-copy)

Comment: @ElderGeek It is not. Note how I do not want to rename files. I want nothing to happen instead.

Comment: I suggest that you read the answer there.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not possible. SCP is simple tool and [automatically overwrites files in destination.](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/scp.c#L1105) You will probably need to put together some `rsync` command to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible with `scp`. The easiest way to do this would probably be using `rsync` with the `--ignore-existing` option, as detailed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14259):

```
rsync --ignore-existing somefile somehost:/some/path/
rsync -r --ignore-existing somedir somehost:/some/path/
```

Note that this will *not* make `rsync` exit if a file already exists; it will just skip it and keep copying.

Comment: But if I am doing a single file, then that is fine, right?

Comment: @Akiva Yes, this will work fine for copying a single file.